# Python exersice to accept a 4 digit bin numbers and put in a list those divisible by 5.

Tags: python

```
result_list = []
nr = int(input("Please enter a 4 digit number made from 0 and 1 : "))

if len(str(nr)) > 4:
    nr = int(input("Please enter a 4 digit number made from 0 and 1 : "))
elif str(nr).split():
    for x in str(nr):
        if x == 0 or x == 1:
            if nr % 5 == 0:
                result_list.append(nr)
            else:
                nr = int(input("Please enter a 4 digit number made from 0 
and 1 : "))
        else:
            nr = int(input("Please enter a 4 digit number made from 0 and 1 
: "))

else:
    print(result_list)
```

I have the following exercise :
"Write a Python program which accepts a sequence of comma separated 4 digit binary numbers as its input and print the numbers that are divisible by 5 in a comma separated sequence."
But i don`t get how to get it done.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is not working with your current code? What specifically is your question so that we can direct our help?

Comment: `if x == 0 or x == 1:` cannot be true because you've converted `nr` to a string. You need to test for equality against strings: `if x in ('0', '1'):`. That alone probably doesn't fix the code but it's one issue to account for.

Comment: Your program is supposed to accept a *sequence* of binary numbers, it's not supposed to ask for them one at a time.

Comment: As for handling binary, here's a hint. Check out what this does: `print(int("1101", 2))`

Comment: The highest possible value, `0b1111 = 15`, so you could just check if the number is 5, 10 or 15

Comment: Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, it's a program that output the will be in a 4 by 2 array with each row being the value and if it's a multiple of 5 or not

```
nb_list = []

# get the input
while not len(nb_list) == 4 :
    bin_nb = str(input("Enter a number"))
    #you could add some verification for the inputs here...
    nb_list.append([int(bin_nb, 2),int(bin_nb, 2) % 5] ) #binary to decimal [ binary number, 1 if multiple 5 else 0 ]

for element in nb_list:
    if element[1] == 0 and element[0] != 0:
        print(element[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is overcomplicated. The main issue is you aren't converting from base2 to (binary) to base10 (regular counting). You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
nums = list(input("Please enter a 4 digit number made from 0 and 1 : ").split(','))
# example: 0101,1000,1001,1010

res = [num for num in nums if not int(num, 2) % 5]

print(res)
# result: ['0101', '1010']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think again about the exact question:

- "accepts a sequence of comma separated 4 digit binary numbers":
  I think the idea is that the user can input something like "0101,1111,0011". You don't address this in your code
- "binary numbers": From my understanding the idea is to convert binary numbers to int and then check it for their divisibility. You don't convert them so far but just interprete the input as int.

So an approach would be:

- Parse a comma separated string to a list of binary(!) numbers
- Convert to int and check for divisibility, collect divisable results in another list
- Return result list as comma separated values